# Click a button on a Chrome web page by using Applescript

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to run an Applescript code to click/access a Button on a webpage. (As it's in Mandarin I can't <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to find it automatically then hit enter to access it.)

The AppleScript was saying the events does not understand `clickClassName` and can’t go on.

So what's the correct AppleScript coding in order to tell the script to click that button?

Here's my wrong AppleScript code, hopefully I can get some help:

```
tell application "System Events"
  clickClassName ("what should I type in here to access to the button???")
end tell
```

the selector for that button is:

```
#app > div > div.resource-layout.ET4 > div:nth-child(2) > div.module-content > div:nth-child(4) > div.section-content > div > div.cover-rightWrap > div.waves-effect.btnSmall.xeBtnDefault.cover-btn
```

---

[image: as attached photo]

[image: attached photo 2]

Many many thanks!!!!

Comment: The `clickClassName` _handler_ should not be within the `tell application "System Events"` _block_.  Also, without seeing the _code_ of the `clickClassName` _handler_, there is not much else to analyze.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! [Please add your Applescript code to the question as text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551), not as an image. Text is easier for us to work with here.

Comment: What happens when you click this button?  What does it do?

Answer (score 1):

Since I cannot test based on the information you've provided in your OP, here is an example of clicking the **Ask Question** *button* on the page of your question, for both **Safari** and **Google Chrome**.

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* was tested in both **Safari** and **Google Chrome** under **macOS High Sierra** and worked as *coded* with this webpage loaded.

**Note**: Do not place the *handler* insider of an *application's* `tell` *block* and it's best not to call the *handler* from within an *application's* `tell` *block*, unless it's appropriate. Calling it from inside a `tell application "System Events"` *block* **is not** appropriate in this use case.

---

**Safari**:

```applescript
tell application "Safari"
    tell current tab of front window
        do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('ws-nowrap s-btn s-btn__primary')[0].click();"
    end tell
end tell
```

**As a *handler***:

```applescript
clickClassName("ws-nowrap s-btn s-btn__primary", 0)

to clickClassName(className, elementNum)
    tell application "Safari"
        tell current tab of front window
            do JavaScript ¬
                "document.getElementsByClassName('" & ¬
                className & ¬
                "')[" & ¬
                elementNum & ¬
                "].click();"
        end tell
    end tell
end clickClassName
```

---

**Google Chrome**:

```applescript
tell application "Google Chrome"
    tell active tab of front window
        execute javascript "document.getElementsByClassName('ws-nowrap s-btn s-btn__primary')[0].click();"
    end tell
end tell
```

**As a *handler***:

```applescript
clickClassName("ws-nowrap s-btn s-btn__primary", 0)

to clickClassName(className, elementNum)
    tell application "Google Chrome"
        tell active tab of front window
            execute javascript ¬
                "document.getElementsByClassName('" & ¬
                className & ¬
                "')[" & ¬
                elementNum & ¬
                "].click();"
        end tell
    end tell
end clickClassName
```

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: The `document`'s [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) method would be more appropriate to utilize here (instead of [`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)) - the OP has provided the necessary selector.

Comment: @RobC, My answer is intended to be a working example of clicking the **Ask Question** _button_ on this page and also where not to place the _handler_ or call it from within **System Events**. I do not have access to the site in question of the OP and therefore I am only willing to provide this basic example. If you feel it should be done differently then please post an answer.

Comment: _@user3439894_ - Yes sure, good answer too - there's nothing wrong with it and it's certainly applicable within the context of the _Ask Question_ button. The OP is very woolly to say the least. However, the _selector_ given in the OP implies the DOM is as per this [index.html](https://paste.ee/p/tXeeZ) at minimum. Access to the site may not be necessary - the DOM can be inferred from the given _selector_. Using `querySelector()` with given _selector_ the handler can be redefined as per [this example](https://paste.ee/p/VqqeF). _(Note: I assume the `div` actually has a `click` event listener)_